# regression lines over subsets in ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot regression lines over two subsets of boxplots in ggplot. however it looks like it is not possible.

Here is the [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4zarc5l4rriwey/uro7.csv?dl=0)

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(VMT,aes(x=size , y=vmt, group=specimen,colour=sex,fill=sex)) +
geom_boxplot()+
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")+
#geom_point()+
ylab("VTM (°C)")+
xlab("size")+
geom_smooth(data=subset(VMT,sex==F),
          aes(mean(size),mean(vmt),      group=specimen,color=sex,method=lm,se=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? Looking at the question, it seemed like you wanted to take the mean of `size` and `vmt` for each specimen and perform linear regression using those values. That was done using `dplyr` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
## df is same as VMT
df <- read.csv("uro7.csv")[,1:7]
df2 <- filter(df, sex == "F") %>%
    group_by(specimen) %>%
    select(-one_of(c("date", "time", "sex", "turn"))) %>%
    summarize_all(mean)
```

`Select` drops four columns and `summarize_all` takes the mean of `size` and `vmt`. Since this preserves the column name, `aes(x = size, y = vmt)` can be included in `ggplot` so that it can be passed to both `geom_boxplot` and `geom_smooth`. On the other hand, `aes(group = specimen, colour = sex, fill = sex)` need to be `geom_boxplot` since `df2` does not have those columns.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=size, y=vmt)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group=specimen,colour=sex,fill=sex))+
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")+
    #geom_point()+
    ylab("VTM (°C)")+
    xlab("size") +
    geom_smooth(data=df2,
        col = "red", method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Also, some comments about the original code:

You should have `sex == "F"` and `method = lm, se = FALSE` should not be included in `aes` (Both have been fixed in my code).